# What is the difference between addsTo and includes in Java's Dagger?

Tags: android, dagger

I am not sure what the difference is?  When should I use which?

http://square.github.io/dagger/javadoc/index.html

Comment: Has already explained this here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24690638/2432060

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`includes` indicates which modules current module is composed of. For example, it's useful for aggregating all your modules statically:

```
@Module(
  includes = { AndroidModule.class, NetworkModule.class, StorageModule.class }
)
public class RootModule() {
}

// other file
objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new RootModule());
```

Instead of dynamically:

```
objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(
     new AndroidModule(), 
     new NetworkModule(), 
     new StorageModule());
```

Thus, fully utilizing compile time graph validation.

`addsTo` relates specifically to parent-child modules' relations. It indicates that module is an extension of some module and is used as `.plus()` parameter. E.g. having two modules:

```
@Module(
  //...
)
public class ParentModule() {
  //...
}

@Module(
  addsTo = { ParentModule.class },
  //...
)
public class ChildModule () {
  //...
}
```

this config means that after `parentGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new ParentModule());` you can execute `childGraph = parentGraph.plus(new ChildModule());` somewhere in your code to create extended, usually, short-lived child graph.

Comment: Thanks. Do you still have to .create the modules programmatically even if you have them declared in the includes @Module section. Basically you have to write them out twice?

Comment: @Kamilski81 Nope. Just create the one that includes others, in my example, `RootModule`.